# How to display ggplot2 on Rshiny main panel

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

The ggplot2 object doesnt display properly in RShiny mainpanel. For recreation, the below code uses iris dataset. Need help

I checked the link - [RShiny ggplot2 not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640678/rshiny-ggplot2-not-showing) , but this didnt help. I also ran through https://shiny.rstudio.com/ website, but nothing had explanation with example on how to display the ggplot2 object. I used renderPlot and renderImage functions, but none gave required results.

'''

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Sample Shiny"),
  navbarPage(
    br(),
    tabPanel(h4("Iris Data"),
             sidebarPanel(
               radioButtons("var1", 
                            label = "Choose a FILL field",
                            choices = c("Species"),
                            selected = "Species"),

      mainPanel(plotOutput("plot",click = "plot_click")))
    )
  ))


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot(
    {
      #browser()
      sw <- input$var1
      ### "a" below is iris dataset which I pass on as input**
      ggplot(data = a) +
           aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = sw) +
           geom_bar() +
           theme_minimal() +
           coord_flip()
    },width = "auto",height = "auto",res = 72)
}

# Run app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

'''

I was hoping to see the graph in the middle of mainpanel, but all I see is a small graph with no proper margins.

Expected: (Something like this on RShiny)
[image]

Here is what I see now: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`input$var1` is a string *=>* use `aes_string`:

```
  ggplot(data = a) +
    aes_string(x = "Sepal.Length", fill = sw) + ......
```

Comment: Hi... the fill is working after using aes_string. However, the graph is visible at one corner. How can I make it move to the main panel?